# Curl/GraphQL command failing with 200

Tags: shell, curl, graphql

I am trying to write a shell script that executes a `curl` against a GraphQL API and I've never interacted with GQL before. I am getting some strange errors and although I understand this community doesn't have access to the GQL server I was hoping someone could take a look at the script and make sure I'm not doing anything flagrantly wrong syntax-wise (both in the shell script layer as well as the GQL query itself).

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

BSEE_WEB_SERVER_DNS=https://mybsee.example.com
BSEE_API_KEY=abc123

siteId=1
scanConfigId=456

runScanQuery='mutation CreateScheduleItem { create_schedule_item(input: {site_id: "$siteId" scan_configuration_ids: "$scanConfigId"}) { schedule_item { id } } }'
runScanVariables='{ "input": "site_id": $scanId }}'
runScanOperationName='CreateScheduleItem'

curl -i --request POST \
    --url $BSEE_WEB_SERVER_DNS/graphql/v1 \
    --header "Authorization: $BSEE_API_KEY" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{"query":"$runScanQuery","variables":{$runScanVariables},"operationName":"${runScanOperationName}"}'
```

And the output when I run the script off the terminal:

```
HTTP/2 200 

<OMITTED RESPONSE HEADERS>

{"errors":[{"message":"Invalid JSON : Unexpected character (\u0027$\u0027 (code 36)): was expecting double-quote to start field name, Line 1 Col 38","extensions":{"code":3}}]}%
```

I am omitting the HTTP response headers for security and brevity reasons.

I am wondering if my use of quotes/double-quotes is somehow wrong, or if there is anything about the nature of the GQL query itself (via curl) that looks off to anyone.

I verified with the team that manages the server that the HTTP 200 OK response code is correct. 200 shows that the request succeeded to the GQL API, but that GQL is responding with this error to indicate the `query` itself is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to modify the GraphQL bits and fix the bash string quoting.

#### runScanQuery GraphQL operation

Fix the GraphQL syntax.  Use a GraphQL [operation name](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#operation-name) `CreateScheduleItem` with [variables](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables)  `$site_id` in the [arguments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#arguments) `input: { site_id: $siteId, scan_configuration_ids: $scanConfigId`:

```
mutation CreateScheduleItem($site_id: String!, $scanConfigId: String!) {
  create_schedule_item(
    input: { site_id: $siteId, scan_configuration_ids: $scanConfigId }
  ) {
    schedule_item {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

#### runScanVariables: JSON

Our mutation expects two variables, which GraphQL will substitute into `CreateScheduleItem($site_id: String!, $scanConfigId: String!)`.  Provide the GraphQL variables as JSON.  Here is the expected output after bash variable substitution:

```json
{ "$site_id": "1", "$scanConfigId": "456" }
```

#### Get the bash quoting right

Finally, translate the inputs into bash-friendly syntax:

```sh
runScanQuery='mutation CreateScheduleItem($site_id: String!, $scanConfigId: String!) { create_schedule_item(input: {site_id: $siteId scan_configuration_ids: $scanConfigId}) { schedule_item { id } } }'
runScanVariables='{"$site_id":"'"$siteId"'","$scanConfigId":"'"$scanConfigId"'"}'  # no spaces!
runScanOperationName='CreateScheduleItem'
data='{"query":"'"$runScanQuery"'","variables":'$runScanVariables',"operationName":"'"$runScanOperationName"'"}'
```

Check our bash formats. Paste the terminal output into a code-aware editor like VSCode.  Expect the editor to parse the output correctly.

```sh
echo $runScanQuery              # want string in graphql format
echo $runScanVariables          # want JSON
echo $data                      # want JSON
```

#### Edit: add a public API example

Here's a complete working example using the public Star Wars API:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
filmId=1
data='{"query":"query Query($filmId: ID) { film(filmID: $filmId) { title }}","variables":{"filmId":"'"$filmId"'"}}'

curl --location --request POST 'https://swapi-graphql.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/index' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data "$data"
```

Responds with `{"data":{"film":{"title":"A New Hope"}}}`.

Comment: Thanks @fedonev (+1) -- so your `data` variable there, could I use it (verbatim) for the `--data` argument of the `curl` in my original question?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup `--data "$data"` if you want to use the data variable instead of the string literal.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup I added a Star Wars API working example demonstrating the correct formats.  May the Force be with you.

Answer (score 0):

In GraphQL **it's normal to always have 200 status code**; client must check response body searching for failures.

The reason is simple: In REST, http is part of the protocol and status code has semantics but **in GraphQL http is not part of the protocol**, you can have GraphQL over serveral transport protocols:

- http: typical scenario [docs](https://graphql.org/learn/best-practices/#http)
- WebSocket: does not provide any "status code like" payload. [sample](https://www.the-guild.dev/blog/graphql-over-websockets)
- MQTT: does not provide any "status code like" payload
- ...

The only way that server tells you something (even failures) is the body.

---

In your case I suggest you [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) to parse json via bash script searching `error` property.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is completely unrelated to GraphQL. You really have wrong JSON.

Error message says **Unexpected character (\u0027$\u0027 (code 36)): was expecting double-quote to start field name, Line 1 Col 38",**

You can replace escaped \u0027 with apostrophe and you will get

**Unexpected character ('$' (code 36)): was expecting double-quote to start field name, Line 1 Col 38",**

So it hates dollar sign at position 38 in what you send as data to curl

```
data='{"query":"'"$runScanQuery"'","variables":'$runScanVariables'
                                                ^
                                               this
```

First - all field names and values in JSON should be wrapped with double quotes, not single.

Second  - if  you want curl to expand env variable, put it to double quotes, not single.